# ”Windows service for the name MySQL already exists”.How to remove MySQL service name which is already there in my pc

Tags: mysql, database

I have been using windows 7 and I installed MySQL in my system. But I am unable to access using MySQL client or command prompt. I tried installing and uninstalling but at after installing three check points it is getting stopped. It says MySQL is already installed. I tried using "sc delete MySQL" which couldn't help me anymore.

Comment: did you try restarting your machine after you ran the sc delete command?

Answer (score 1):

- open cmd as administrator and run this command:
- "sc delete MySQL" where "MySQL" is the name of the service.
  -restart pc

Answer (score 0):

It's true, I also faced the same problem and messed my system for two days. But later I could figure out the problem. Actually there was a previous installation of MySQL through Xampp Server. this new installation was unable to cope up with the Xampp MySQL which resulted in all the mistakes.
Uninstall the XAMPP or their equivalents first and all MySQL if exists
and reinstall it. I hope it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

type in window icon-services,
 type cmd in windows icon don't press enter, on cmd right click run configuration-then in cmd type sc delete service name.
example:
C:\Windows\system32>sc delete MySQL
       press enter
then it will show
[sc] DeleteService SUCCESS